# How to add KotlinPoet dependency to simple console app?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlinpoet

I'm writing a simple console app which should to generate some kotlin code on execution. I faced a strange problem I can't add KotlinPoen dependency. My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'kotlin'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation group: 'com.squareup', name: 'kotlinpoet', version: '1.7.2'
}
```

But in PoetApp.kt import failed with message `Unresolved reference: squareup`:

```kotlin
import com.squareup.kotlinpoet.FunSpec

object PoetApp {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(vararg param: String) {
        val main = FunSpec.builder("main")
            .addCode("""
        |var total = 0
        |for (i in 0 until 10) {
        |    total += i
        |}
        |""".trimMargin())
            .build()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared Java compatibility with version 1.7, but this version of kotlinpoet will work only with 1.8 and higher, see the [library gradle file](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/blob/d354dc8a55a5aa262f5c7ca88d2be57f228f5c3c/build.gradle.kts#L49) and also some compatibility issue solved [here](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/issues/999).

So your build.gradle should look like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'kotlin'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation group: 'com.squareup', name: 'kotlinpoet', version: '1.7.2'
}
```